# Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know if someone could help me. I'm learning now ROR and have run in some troubles.
I have created other_users and post model using scaffold. other_users has many:posts and so one.
The idea is that, when the user is logged in and creates a Post, in show action shows the name of the user which created this post.
 I would like to know if someone can tel me with this.

Post controller

```
def new
    @post = Post.new(:other_user_id => @other_user.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Post view _form:

```
<%= form_for(:post, :url => {:action => 'create', :other_user_id => @other_user.id}) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I know that something is wrong with that, but i'm quite new with that so i can't figure it out on my own

Comment: Karlis-  just check @other_user having values into it or not or you are receiving nil object.

Comment: Have same problem., PLz guide..

Comment: We need some more information. Are you getting this error in the "show" action? If so, we need to see the code from the controller and view for that action. Usually rails will also identify the specific line # in which the error is occurring. That will help us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 2 `@other_user` is not known so it is nil. We are trying to get the id from a nil so it yields error called `called id for nil`. Initialize `@other_user` and try again.