# How to fix Ruby on Rails obj != nil error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null

I'm trying to ensure that an object is not nil in Ruby on Rails and I'm getting this error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

This is what the object looks like in the debugger (it is not nil):

[image]

How do I correctly check for nil in this case?  All cases?

I've found some similar posts but not this specific case:
[Check for nil gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213930/check-for-nil-gives-error), and 
[Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208927/called-id-for-nil-which-would-mistakenly-be-4-if-you-really-wanted-the-id-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!=` comparator is using the `id` to check equality. So it is checking if `ob1.id != ob2.id`, or in your case `map_set.id != nil.id`

To check if an object is nil, you can simply check if the object has a value. `if object` or `if !object.nil?`

Comment: Thanks, coming from Java it was very counter intuitive to try to perform an operation with "." on a potentially null/nil object.  I'm sure I'm the first person to trip up on this ;)

Comment: @John All objects in Ruby inherit from Object, so there's many methods that are always callable regardless, like `nil.to_s` is valid. Testing vs. `nil` explicitly is rarely needed since Ruby has a very strict definition of what "false" is: `nil` and `false` only. Unless you need to differentiate between a potentially literal `false` value, `if (x)` is sufficient. There's no need for `if (!x.nil?)`